# Find the host name in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible with easy syntax like MS SQL Server do

```
SELECT HOST_NAME()
```

in postgresql 9.3.2?
I have read some articles but no result !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598517/find-the-host-name-and-port-using-psql-commands

Comment: @vijay4vijju I already read the article before, but I'm not found the answer

Comment: @ntalbs that's the ip and the port, not the hostname. Still not the answer that i'm looking for

Comment: Which hostname do you want? The one where Postgres is running or the one from the current client?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name current client

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would you want the behavior to be if the IP address of the client has multiple hostnames defined in DNS?  I have seen dozens of hostnames associated with a single IP address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the default build doesn't have that. It is easy however to extend PostgreSQL with new native functions and someone already did it: http://pgxn.org/dist/hostname/ .

Another way would be to install an additional db language (PostgreSQL is great like that - you have the option of using arbitrary languages instead of pl/pgsql) and use the language's own functions to do that. There are e.g. pl/python (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpython-funcs.html) and pl/perl (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plperl-trusted.html -- see also the discussion about trusted and untrusted languages).

Comment: Ok, so the answer is default build doesn't have it. Thanks.