# PostgreSQL 9.3: Query to get hostname,port number and username

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I want to write a query which should result me the following details:

1. Host,
2. Port,
3. Username.

Like we get in the PgAdmin as shown in the below picture:

[image]

As per a_horse_with_no_name said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598517/find-the-host-name-and-port-using-psql-commands) gives me only port number.

Comment: What does the query `SELECT * FROM pg_settings` show you?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, There are many things out there around 227 rows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT CURRENT_USER usr
      ,inet_server_addr() host -- use inet_client_addr() to get address of the remote connection
      ,inet_server_port() port -- use inet_client_port() to get port of the remote connection
```

---

[System Information Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-info.html)

Comment: After running your query I get the host `::1`? Does that mean `localhost`?

Comment: The OS  is window 7.

Comment: @mak what is the result for `select inet_client_addr()`

Comment: @MAK check this `select usename, client_addr from pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity;`

Comment: @MAK `::1` is the IPv6 version of localhost: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Answer (score 4):

Try it for host Name

```
select *
from pg_settings
where name = 'listen_addresses'
```

Comment: What does column `boot_val` indicates?

Comment: @MAK am check the `short_desc` column read that description so only posted

Comment: I belive start `*` or `localhost` would be the most popular results :)

Answer (score 0):

Building on w͏̢in̡͢g͘̕ed̨p̢͟a͞n͏͏t̡͜͝he̸r̴'s answer above;

```
SELECT CURRENT_USER usr, :'HOST' host, inet_server_port() port;
```

This uses psql's built in HOST variable, documented [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-VARIABLES)

Comment: An interesting approach, but worth noting: this only works in the `psql` tool, not using other clients, and for a Unix socket connection it returns the socket path.