# Spring Boot gives an error of URL must start with 'jdbc'

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I am trying to configure a Postgres database in spring boot using annotation configuration. I have all the database credentials in a file named `database.properties` and the configuration file is called `DBconfig.java`

```
database.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydb 
database.driverClassName= com.postgresql.jdbc.Driver
database.username= postgres
database.password= password
```

The dbConfig file -

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:databaseAccess/database.properties")

public class DBconfig {

  @Value("${username}")
  private String username;

  @Value("${password}")
  private String password;

  @Value("${url}")
  private String url;

  @Bean
  @Qualifier("postgresDB")
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    DataSourceBuilder dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSource.url(url);
    dataSource.password(password);
    //dataSource.driverClassName(driverClassName);
    dataSource.username(username);
    return dataSource.build();
  }

  @Bean
  @Qualifier("jdbcTemplate")
  public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
      return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
  }
}
```

This is my main file

```
     @SpringBootApplication
     public class GetNotificationsApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

           ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DBconfig.class);
           JdbcTemplate template= ctx.getBean("jdbcTemplate", JdbcTemplate.class);
           template.execute("CREATE TABLE TEST( test VARCHAR(20))");

        }

     }
```

I keep getting the error
Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'

Comment: Does value in url has proper value as it's in properties file?

Comment: Yup  I started a Postgres server on my computer at port 8080.

Comment: Postgres server at 8080 then which port your spring app is running?

Comment: Whoops sorry I meant 5432 the standard port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change value for url parameter by defining port number for postgres. Assuming that postgres is running on 5432 which is the default port.

Change

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydb
```

To

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
```

For port number check [Find the host name and port using PSQL commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5598517/6572971)

UPDATE:

Also change `@Value("${username}")` to `@Value("${database.username}")` and other properties too by prefix `database`.

Comment: I did change it but It still is giving the same error.

Comment: Got the issue...check answer now.